# ¿Podéis decirme que es una lambda en Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

Estoy estudiando ahora mismo Kotlin, pero no me queda claro que son las lambdas por más que leo y leo por internet, las veces que las he usado es porque el propio IDE me lo ha sugerido, pero nunca habia parado a ver que eran en profundidad, asi que agradezco una explicación de alguien que pueda darmela, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Una expresión lambda es una subrutina la cual se envía como argumento a otra función para parametrizar su ejecución, esta función que recibe una expresión lambda como parámetro es llamada [función de orden  superior](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_de_orden_superior).

Algunos lenguajes actualmente incorporan el uso de lambdas como  en el caso de `Android` los lenguajes `Java` (desde [Java 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)) y `kotlin`.

---

Ejemplos:

Un ejemplo de como incorporar una expresión lambda en Android, a partir de un listener designado a un botón

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(
  new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View vista){

       doSomething();

    }
});
```

usando una expresión lambda lo anterior puede ser únicamente:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener( vista -> doSomething(vista) }
```

en este caso el parámetro del listener es reemplazado por una expresión lambda que tiene como parámetro un objeto View (vista).

---

Usando [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) comúnmente usado para operaciones Asyncronas en segundo plano:

```
val executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2)
async(executor){
    doSomething()
    uiThread{
         //Actualiza UI
         ui.update()
    }
}
```

https://jamie.mccrindle.org/posts/exploring-kotlin-standard-library-part-3/

---

Llenando datos en elmento de Adapter:

En lugar de

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: myViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val articulo : articulos[position]

  holder.name = articulo.name
  holder.price = articulo.price
  holder.model = articulo.model
}
```

cambiaría a:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: myViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val articulo : articulos[position]

  with(articulo){
    holder.name = name
    holder.price = price
    holder.model = model
  }
}
```

---

Puedes ver más en la documentación oficial de `Kotlin`:

**[Funciones de Orden superior y Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)**

Comment: Creo que en tu definición: `una subrutina la cual se envía como argumento a otra función` también entran `callbacks` como los de `javascript` y `apuntadores a funciones` como los de `c/c++`

Answer (score 2):

El **cálculo lambda** es un sistema formal diseñado para investigar la definición de `función`, la noción de `aplicación de funciones` y la `recursión`.**Debe tomarse la definición de función desde el punto de vista matematico y no desde el punto de vista de la programación.**

Fue introducido por Alonzo Church y Stephen Kleene en la década de 1930; Church usó el cálculo lambda en 1936 para resolver el `Entscheidungsproblem`. 
Puede ser usado para definir de manera limpia y precisa qué es una "`función computable`".

Se puede considerar al cálculo lambda como el lenguaje universal de programación más pequeño. Consiste en una regla de transformación simple (sustitución de variables) y un esquema simple para definir funciones.

El **cálculo lambda** es universal porque cualquier función computable puede ser expresada y evaluada a través de él. Por lo tanto, **es equivalente a las máquinas de Turing.**

Al uso de alguna función de **calculo lambda** en lenguajes de programación se les denomina "**expresiones lambda**".De hecho **el paradigma de la programación funcional** tiene sus raíces en el **cálculo lambda** y tiene una gran influencia sobre los lenguajes funcionales, como `Lisp`, `ML` y `Haskell`.

**Java** desde el JDK 8 soporta funciones anónimas, denominadas `Expresiones Lambda`.
​Una **expresión lambda en Java** consiste en una lista separada por comas de los parámetros formales encerrados entre paréntesis, un símbolo de flecha (->) y un cuerpo. 
Los tipos de datos de los parámetros siempre se pueden omitir, al igual que los paréntesis si sólo hay un parámetro. El cuerpo puede consistir en una sentencia o un bloque de sentencia.

```
// with no parameter
() -> System.out.println("Hello, world.")

// Con un parámetro (este ejemplo es una función de identidad).
a -> a

// Con una expresión
(a, b) -> a + b

// Con información de tipo explícita
(long id, String name) -> "id: " + id + ", name:" + name

// Con un bloque de código
(a, b) -> { return a + b; }

// Con múltiples afirmaciones en el cuerpo lambda. Necesita un bloque de código.
// Este ejemplo también incluye dos expresiones lambda anidadas (la primera también es una clausura).
(id, defaultPrice) -> {
  Optional<Product> product = productList.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == id).findFirst();
  return product.map(p -> p.getPrice()).orElse(defaultPrice);
}​
```

En **Kotlin** es similar:

```
{
   param1, param2 -> //parámetros separados por coma
   param1 + param2 //código a ejecutar

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lamba es el equivalente a la función de flecha de javascript básicamente es para substituir código redundante suele salir cuando estas programando cuando generas un listener.

**Ejemplo sin lambda:**

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Código
    }
});
```

**Ejemplo con lambda:**

```
boton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    //Código
});
```

Comment: Ya si, eso si lo se, pero ¿que más código aparte de eso se puede sustituir? He visto que en Kotlin se usa bastante.

Comment: Básicamente es en ese contexto dónde se usa creo que no hay otros

Comment: Hay más, no es solo para el onClick, he visto un curso de Kotlin donde lo usan muuuuchas más veces, solo que no consigo entenderlo.